# Show element only on new session and refresh

Tags: javascript, html

The task here is to show an element only for the "first" time when you open the webpage and if you are refreshing the webpage.
Links in navigation redirect you to another *.html page and the "global" div element that is included in every *.html page should only be shown, if you:

1. opened the webpage for the first time (closing the webpage / tab, and opening it again counts as opening the website as first time as well)
2. refreshed the page being on the website.

The file structure and approximate code is as illustrated here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ocytv4?file=index.html

I am so used to do SPA, so I am not even sure that's possible to do in plain JS, because the webpage is always unloaded and loaded again.

I tried adding session storage item to check against, but in this case it is not possible to remove `.introduction` on refresh.
I tried checking the document.referrer and the actual window.location.href to no avail as well, there are inconsistencies.
For example, I could do:

```
const ref = document.referrer
const href = window.location.href
const showIntro = () => {
    introductionNode.classList.remove('hidden')
}

if (!ref || ref === href) {
    removeIntro()
} else {
    removeIntro()
}
```

But, apparently when I arrive to the Page1 from Page2, my referrer will be Page1 and will not be set to Page2, so when refreshing the page, introduction block is not hidden. And can only work if I click on the link in the navigation for the second time, being on the same page.

Comment: So far the only solution I found is to check for document.referrer existence (if it's not null or emptyy string) and performance.navigation.type = if it's 1, then it was reloaded, if it's 0 then it's not reloaded :)
But I am a little afraid of depreciation of performance.navigation